# undefined function highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi I have been using highcharts and highstock for a year now and there has been no problem but suddenly when I load my website I am getting the below error:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function highcharts.js:22a.fn.

I have arranged all the libraries in the correct order and path and I did not get these errors before but now I am getting them.
Please help me!

I even tried previous stack overflow answers but none of them helped

Comment: Have you loaded any new libraries or updated their version (jquery, etc)? Any changes to your data/code?

Comment: No absolutely no changes have been made..I am also getting the below error in one of the charts..Uncaught type Reference error in d3.v3.js

Comment: Is there a conflict between d3 and highcharts maybe?

Comment: No there arent my charts have been working well for many months now. Do you need the code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6xdqszay/   This is the link to the code

Comment: Okay, why is jQuery missing? Include jQuery or standalone framework.. [see docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation).

Comment: Sorry i missed jquery while copying the code onto fiddle but its there in my code and it still doesnt work.